# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AR118' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

The SP below is returning the following error:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AR118' to data type int.

No idea what is going on, at the bottom a test SP that calls it...

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_ProyectoIngresar]

```
@IDUsuario varchar(20),
@CodigoPais char(2),
@Nombre varchar(255), 
@Alias char(25), 
@Sector char(3), 
@AporteFonPlata decimal(9), 
@AporteLocal decimal(9), 
@IDResponsable varchar(20), 
@Reembolsable char(1),
@NoProyecto char(5) OUT

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @Fecha datetime
declare @No int
set @No = 0
set @Fecha = GetUtcDate()
set @NoProyecto = ''

Select @NoProyecto = max(NoProyecto) from Proyectos WHERE Substring(NoProyecto,1,2) = @CodigoPais

if @NoProyecto is NULL
   BEGIN
   SET @NoProyecto = @CodigoPais + '101'
   END
else
    begin
        set @No = CAST(SUBSTRING(@NoProyecto, 3, 3) as int) + 1
        set @NoProyecto = @CodigoPais + RIGHT('000' + CAST(@No AS    Varchar(3)), 3 )
    end

Insert Into Proyectos 
            (
            NoProyecto, Estado, FechaEstado, HoraEstado, Nombre, Alias, Sector, 
            AporteFonPlata, AporteLocal, AporteOtros,
            AprobacionEstimada, AprobacionProbabilidad, IDResponsable, 
            FechaAbstracto, EstadoAbstracto, FechaPerfil, EstadoPerfil, 
            FechaPOperativa, EstadoPOperativa, FechaNegociacion, EstadoNegociacion, 
            FechaAprobacion, EstadoAprobacion, Reembolsable,  
            Objetivo, Componentes, Beneficiarios, Ubicacion, NoResolucion, 
            IDingresado, FechaIngresado, IDModificado, FechaModificado
            )
VALUES      (
            @NoProyecto, 'INA', @Fecha, '', @Nombre, @Alias, @Sector, 
            @AporteFonPlata, @AporteLocal, 0, 0, '', @IDResponsable, 
            @Fecha, 'N', @Fecha, 'N', @Fecha, 'N', @Fecha, 'N', @Fecha, 'N', 
            @Reembolsable, '', '', '', '', '', 
            @IDUsuario, @Fecha, @IDUsuario, @Fecha
            )

if scope_identity() is NULL
    begin
        set @NoProyecto = ''
    end

return @NoProyecto
```

END

The testing SP

```
declare @IDUsuario varchar(20)
declare @CodigoPais char(2)
declare @Nombre varchar(255)
declare @Alias char(25)
declare @Sector char(3)
declare @AporteFonplata decimal(9,0)
declare @AporteLocal decimal(9,0)
declare @Reembolsable char(1)
declare @IDResponsable varchar(20)
declare @NoProyecto char(5)

set @IDUsuario = 'TRESPONSABLE'
set @CodigoPais = 'AR'
set @Nombre = 'Ingreso Nuevo Proyecto'
set @Alias = 'NUEVO'
set @Sector = 'SOC'
set @AporteFonplata = 25000000
set @AporteLocal = 5000000
set @Reembolsable = 'S'
set @IDresponsable = 'TRESPONSABLE'
set @NoProyecto = ''

EXEC PA_ProyectoIngresar @IDUsuario, @CodigoPais, @Nombre, @Alias, @Sector, @AporteFonplata, @AporteLocal, @IDresponsable, @Reembolsable, @NoProyecto
```

Comment: The clue is in the error message your code tries to convert `'AR118'` string into an int value, and it is not possible because it has the charaters `AR` cannot be converted to INT.

Comment: that is my problem, I can't find where the SP is trying the conversion from char to int, what am I overlooking?

Comment: What is the datatype of your 'NoProyecto' column in table Proyectos.

Comment: the column is defined as char(5) in the table

Comment: Please post the DDL of your table so people here can immediately point you to right direction.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Proyectos](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [NoProyecto] [char](5) NOT NULL,
 [Estado] [char](3) NULL,
 [FechaEstado] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Proyectos_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code sets the value @NoProyecto to string 'AR001', and when you try to insert this string into column `NoProyecto` of table `Proyectos` sql server tries to convert it to INT datatype.

I believe column `NoProyecto` is an INT column.

```
declare @CodigoPais char(2)
declare @NoProyecto char(5)
declare @No int
set @No = 0

set @CodigoPais = 'AR'
set @NoProyecto = ''

if @NoProyecto is NULL
   BEGIN
   SET @NoProyecto = @CodigoPais + '101'
   END
else
    begin
        set @No = CAST(SUBSTRING(@NoProyecto, 3, 3) as int) + 1
        set @NoProyecto = @CodigoPais + RIGHT('000' + CAST(@No AS    Varchar(3)), 3 )
    end

SELECT @NoProyecto
```

Comment: NoProyecto in Proyectos is char(5)